# how to solve blank home page error in wordpress

Tags: apache, wordpress

getting blank home page, but admin is working fine for me.
i tried to put 
define('WP_DEBUG', true) in config file but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check errors in error_log to see where code breaks or try to remove some newly installed plugins